# Spark: Executors have different tasks

Tags: apache-spark

I use Spark 2.4.3 with 12 executors, each with 5 cores and 40 memories. I set `defaultParallelism` to 180.

I use the following code to read two single text files from hdfs.

```
val f1 = sc.textFile("file1", sc.defaultParallelism)
val f2 = sc.textFile("file2", sc.defaultParallelism)

val all = f1.union(f2).persist()
all.count()
```

When I look at the Spark UI, I find that executors get different number of tasks (some get only 3). Why not Spark assign the same # of tasks to executors so that the maximum efficiency can be obtained? Is there a way to avoid this?

[image: Executors]

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to keep in mind...

- not all tasks take the same amount of time.  I find 2x or 4x often times is a better # of tasks.
- scheduling has a bit of overhead.
- the spark ui can make it difficult to determine to utilization rate of the cluster since a single executor task slot is scattered around the graph.
- IMO you don't want to optimize executor utilization rate.  What you want to optimize is either query latency or throughput per cpu.  You can very easily over parallelize spark jobs and cause them to be extremely inefficient.